# How do I create a certain graph using pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

[image: wanted]

I can't create this graph or something similar to it. I use [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) for plotting.

Comment: This is not a 'please do it for me' site so please show us some code of what you tried so far. (Note: I don't know [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) myself but you probably won't get must help the way your question is formulated now.)

Comment: Is tikz an option to you? You can find many examples here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible solution with `pgfplots`. Here internal labels `x\i` and `y\i` are defined alone the blue line via `coordinate[pos=xx]` where `0 < xx < 1`. Then vertical lines with relative distance are drawn from the points on the blue line. The distance is given via `\h` variable. Lastly, label the `\epsilon_1` and `y_i, \hat y`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\pgfplotsset{every axis x label/.style={
  at={(1,0)},  below,  yshift=-5pt},
  every axis y label/.style={ at={(0,1)},
  left,xshift=-5pt}
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[ymax=5,ymin=0,,xmin=0,xmax=10,
    axis lines=left, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    ytick={2,4},xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    yticklabels={$y_i$, $\hat y_x$},
    xtick={0},
    ]
\addplot+[domain=1:10,mark=none, thick] {1 + 0.25*x} 
\foreach \i/\p in {1/0.2,2/0.4,3/0.6,4/0.8}{
coordinate[pos=\p] (x\i)   % define vertical points for upward direction
}
\foreach \i/\p in {1/0.3,2/0.5,3/0.7,4/0.9}{
coordinate[pos=\p] (y\i)   % define vertical points for downward direction
};
\end{axis}
% draw lines showing variances
\foreach \i/\h in {1/0.5,2/0.5,3/1.2,4/0.5}{
\draw (x\i) --++ (0,\h);                   % relative distance for height upward
}
\foreach \i/\h in {1/0.5,2/1.2,3/0.5,4/0.7}{
\draw (y\i) --++ (0,-\h) coordinate(e\i);  % relative distance for height upward
}
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=1pt}] 
(y2)--(e2) node [midway,right,xshift=5pt] {\footnotesize $\epsilon_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```